# SearchView in Firebase RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to add Filter Recyclerview data using searchview.I tried many ways but didn't get what I want.Iam using fireBase Recycleradapter.and couldn't able to get how to use Query to search the title.Iam getting Names of different person and their images.I want to search by person name.Ad then further on click on name Profile of that person opens up.

List Activity:

```
public class WrestlersListActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<WrestlersNamesModel> model;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WrestlersNamesModel, WrestlersViewHolder> adapter;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TextView toolbarText;
    List<WrestlersNamesModel> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wrestlers_list);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.listtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.wrestlers_names_recycler);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Content").child("Wrestlers");
        model = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<WrestlersNamesModel>()
                .setQuery(reference, WrestlersNamesModel.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<WrestlersNamesModel, WrestlersViewHolder>(model) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WrestlersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull WrestlersNamesModel wrestlersNamesModel) {

                holder.name.setText(wrestlersNamesModel.getName());

                String imageLink =wrestlersNamesModel.getImages().get(0);

              Picasso.get().load(imageLink).into(holder.wrestlerProfileImage);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {

                    final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(WrestlersListActivity.this,WrestlersProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.user_id,user_id);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.imageLink,imageLink);
                    startActivity(intent);
                });
            }
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public WrestlersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.wrestlers_list_cardview, parent, false);
                return new WrestlersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.startListening();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.stopListening();
       }
    }
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adapter != null) {
            adapter.startListening();
        }  }}
```

Comment: Hello Umair, welcome to StackOverflow. It's unclear where your search code is, or what specific problem you're facing. Pasting code alone, is not enough to determine what can be happening; you're going to try to be more explicit and paste the relevant sections of code where you perform Action X and expect Action Y to happen or something similar.

Comment: https://youtu.be/GkcQWsojLFE

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Hello,Thanks for your time,actually I want to implement searchView in this activity but I didnt understand where to start or what to do

Answer (score 0):

Try researching through debug, console print or log, or even toasts in-app about the *reference* queries inside your FirebaseRecyclerOptions<> declaration. There are also many other parameters in FirebaseDatabase queries, such as orderByKey(), orderByChild(), etc... Also I recommend putting *.setLifecycleOwner(this)* to your FirebaseRecycleOptions inside your search function.